# Database many columns vs one string column processed at runtime

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

The obvious answer is that having one column as a string is pointless because you cannot perform any decent database queries on it. But say that you wanted to store user information, for example, such as their privacy preferences for their username, name and email (etc....).

Would having this as a single column named, for example, "settings" be better performance wise since these variables are not used with any other models?

This variable would be something like "{username => true, name => true, email => false}" and can be processed at runtime.

Comment: it depends on which runtime do you use, if for example you use C++ you can whole database store with file(joke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string that you're creating would consume more space than storing the separate columns, so the table rows would be larger, and caching on the database server would be less efficient. I don't see a potential performance benefit at all.

I think that the only situations in which this might be acceptable database practice are:

1. Where you only ever treat the string that represents many data elements as a single itme of information: for example if you wanted to store a copy of a JSON or XML message that you have received or transmitted.
2. Where the data item represents a set of data elements that you could not know in advance, and you do not have the resources to use something like a key-value store for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors to consider in performance.  If the connection, or your database server is slow then you might be correct in doing what you suggest (to improve performance).

However, keep in mind that you still have to parse the string.

In most professional projects this would be considered horrible practice.  Doing it like you suggests makes the code very un-maintainable.  It opens the door to using the same field for a variety of thing, like favorite color, and such.

If you are tinkering in your basement, do this, but know it is horrible if you want to make a living writing code.